# Circuit breaker with back-out Queue

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route that receives messages, enriches the message by connecting to various resources, and then something more with the enriched message. Some of the resources may occasionally be unavailable. In those cases, the error-handling will place the message on a back-out queue, which will be polled later.

- Receives messages
- Attempts to enrich, using resources
- Error-handler detecting certain unavailable resources

I want to save such messages (say on a queue that is polled on a schedule).
This is like a circuit-breaker pattern. The essence of the pattern would be this:

1. Poll a "back-out" queue on a schedule, and increment the "retry-count" in the message
2. Error handler places messages on back-out queue for a particular type of exception
3. Control Bus detects retries and slows down the polling frequency, or even suspends the polling for a while...like "circuit-breaker"

[image]

I'm wondering if I need to "roll my own" thing, by combining some Camel components? Or is there a component that meets the entire use-case? Reading the section on Hystrix in "Camel In Action", it does not look like it is meant for this use-case.

Any thoughts on some Camel components that could fit into this use-case neatly?

Comment: I doubt there is a component that meets the entire use-case. You need to combine different components. Once the message is on the queue, you can have the control-bus to trigger a route who's only job is to fetch the message and put it on the original route and increase the retry count via some header.

Comment: Thank's for the reply. We also have the complication of wanting multiple "pods" to be servicing this simultaneously, if possible :)

Comment: What do you mean by multiple pods?

Comment: Multiple copies of the same service, deployed on OpenShift, each running in its own little VM-like Kubernetes "POD"
The implication is that coordination/control would also be needed across the different VMs.